# Passing props from parent component to child component on dialog box vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

So I want to bind batch_code data from `dashboard.vue` parent to `review.vue` child component

so, the dashboard contains details like the batch_code, then I have trouble passing the data to the review component, of which it will get the batch_code upon clicking the "Rate and Review" button

when I did try, I am just getting null values from returning said data. any suggestions?

`dashboard.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <v-col cols="10" class="mx-auto">
      <v-card class="pa-4" outlined>
        <v-card-title class="pb-0 pt-2">Dashbard</v-card-title>
        <div v-if="checkifEmpty()">
          <v-row>
            <v-col
              v-for="item in myBatch.all_batch"
              :key="item.batch_code"
              cols="6"
            >
              <v-card class="ma-2" outlined>
                <div class="d-flex">
                  <v-avatar class="ma-3" size="150" tile>
                    <v-img :src="item.image"></v-img>
                  </v-avatar>
                  <div>
                    <v-card-title class="pb-0 pt-2"
                      >{{ item.offer }} ({{ item.level }})</v-card-title
                    >
                    <v-card-text>
                      <div class="mt-0">{{ item.techer_name }}</div>
                      <div class="mt-0">{{ item.batch_name }}</div>
                      <div class="Heading 6 pb-0">
                        {{ item.start_date }} -
                        {{ item.end_date }}
                      </div>
                      <div class="subtitle-1 pb-0">{{ item.type }}</div>
                    </v-card-text>
                  </div>
                  <v-btn elevation="3" v-on:click="openReviewDialog"
                    >Rate and Review!</v-btn
                  >
                </div>
              </v-card>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </div>
        <div v-else>
          <v-card-text class="pb-0 pt-2"
            >You have no enrolled offers</v-card-text
          >
        </div>
      </v-card>
    </v-col>
    <review />
  </div>
  
</template>

<script>
import store from "../../store/index";
import review from "./review"
export default {
  name: "Dashboard",
  components:{
    review,
  },
  computed: {
    myBatch() {
      return store.getters.getMyOffers;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    checkifEmpty() {
      let batch = this.myBatch;
      if (batch == null || batch.all_batch.length == 0) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    },
    openReviewDialog() {
      this.$store.dispatch("setreviewDialog");
      this.sidebarFront = false;
    }
  },
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

‍‍‍`review.vue`

```js
<template>

  <v-row justify="center">
    <v-dialog v-model="reviewDialog" persistent max-width="900px">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title class="justify-center">
          <span class="headline font-weight-bold"
            >Rate and Review this Course!</span
          >
        </v-card-title>
        <v-card-text>
          <v-container fluid>
            <v-row>
              <v-col cols="12" sm="12" md="12">
                <v-form
                  ref="userReview"
                  v-model="userReviewForm"
                  lazy-validation
                >
                   <v-text-field
                    rounded
                    outlined
                    v-model="subject"
                    label="Subject"
                    required
                  ></v-text-field>

                  <v-text-field
                    rounded
                    outlined
                    v-model="batch_code"
                    label="batch_code"
                    readonly
                  ></v-text-field>

                  <v-textarea
                    rounded
                    outlined
                    v-model="review"
                    counter="250"
                    label="Review"
                    required
                  ></v-textarea>
                  
                  <v-rating v-model="rating">
                   <template v-slot:item="props">
                     <v-icon
                     :color="props.isFilled ? 'orange lighten-1' : 'grey lighten-1'"
                      size = "30"
                     @click="handleRatingChange(props)">mdi-star</v-icon>
                    </template>
                  </v-rating> 

                  

                  <div>
                    <v-btn
                      :loading="loginLoader"
                      large
                      block
                      rounded
                      elevation="0"
                      color="primary"
                      @click="submit"
                    >
                      Submit
                    </v-btn>
                  </div>
                </v-form>
              </v-col>
            </v-row>
          </v-container>
        </v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <div class="close"> <v-btn color="error" text @click="closeReviewDialog()"> Close </v-btn></div>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </v-row>
  
</template>

<script>
import store from "../../store/index";

export default {
  props: {
    item:{
          batch_code: null;
       }
          },
  name: "review",
  data() {
    return {
      getters: store.getters,
      rating: null
    };
  },
  computed: {
    reviewDialog: function () {
      return this.getters.getreviewDialog;
    },
    
  },
  methods: {
    closeReviewDialog: function () {
      //this.show = false;
      //this.$refs.card.hide();
      //store.dispatch("removeLoginError");
      store.dispatch("setreviewDialog");
    },
    handleRatingChange(props){
      console.log(props.index + 1)
      this.rating = props.index +1
    }
  },
};
</script>
'''

p.s: i don't know if it's different when calling props for a component than to a dialog box.
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly you've tried? How did you try to pass the data from parent component to the child component? It would help if you only paste the relevant code, not the whole components ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just update your code like below tips,

```
openReviewDialog() {
      this.$store.dispatch("setreviewDialog", **your_rating_data**);
      this.sidebarFront = false;
    }
```

so update your dispatch/action accordingly in store.

and when loading your form just pull data from the store using **getter** and show on dialog.